# how can I get rid of duplicate administrators on 2 macbook pro's

Tags: macbook

I got a new MacBook Pro (insurance payout) and passed my old one (previous generation MacBookPro 2008) on to a staff member whose MacBook Pro died.  I used carbon copy to move my data to the new laptop but couldn't do the same with her move as the older Macbook wouldn't allow it as it was on an old OS.

Ended up just migrating her software onto my old MBP. Now however, they both have the same admin identities and her computer is synching with my mobile me account.

Can I change the administrator identity and save all her applications? I am hoping that I don't have to wipe and reinstall everything to change her computers identity.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what exactly you did when you "migrated her software". If you just copied the Applications to the new machine's `/Applications` directory, they are independent of user accounts.

You can create a new user account in *System Preferences » Accounts* under her name and give it administrative privileges. The problem is that **this account will not contain any of her files or personal settings**, it'll be like a store-bought machine (albeit with some software pre-installed). This is also where you can delete your old account (though I'd keep it for a while, just in case).

Her personal *files* (documents, images, etc.) can easily be moved to the new account -- the problem are the preferences for her applications.

Personal preferences and application support files are stored in `~/Library` -- this is where both **your** old settings (mobile me etc.) and **her** current settings are stored.

I don't see an option here except either deleting all your old stuff (sign out of MobileMe in *System Preferences » MobileMe*) you might also want to clear your stored browser passwords from your keychain using `/Applications/Utilities/Keychain Access.app`, your Mail accounts, your locally stored Mail attachments, etc.), or creating a new account for her, as described above. In the latter case, she'd likely have to reconfigure some applications -- depending of course on what she actually does on that machine.